# Change CSS On Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make each of them separated.

```
<div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">This will change b element</div>
<div id="b">This is element b</div>

<div id="f" onmouseover="chbg('blue')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">This will change g element</div>
<div id="g">This is element g</div>

<div id="j" onmouseover="chbg('yellow')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">This will change k element</div>
<div id="k">This is element k</div>
```

Here is JS

```
function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById('b').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById('g').style.backgroundColor = color;    
    document.getElementById('k').style.backgroundColor = color;    
}
```

Doesn't work properly here http://jsfiddle.net/qUzn5/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to put a second argument in your function like this:

JavaScript:
`function chbg(color, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;

}`

HTML:
(Repeat the div's)

`<div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red', 'a')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">This will change b element</div>`

Comment: @user3858546 , [It works like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/qUzn5/2/). +1, good answer!;)

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!! THANKS!

Comment: @user3858546 Exclamation of happiness and excitement? ;)

Comment: @user3858546 **YAY** Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently they all get colored because the function calls each of the ids

I guess you should add a variable to your javascript function. This variable contains the id of the element to be changed.

I do not know anything of javascript, but i guess it should look like this:

```
function chbg(id,color) {
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this with jQuery so I'm going to assume you're using that. If so, cut down your code a bit like this...

$('#b').css('background-color', color);

If you're using jquery you shouldn't need to use getElementById and .style.

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

And since your function has everything in it, each background will change.

If you must use javascript instead of CSS, try passing a different argument to your function. Perhaps the ID of the background that should change. Then set conditionals in your function according to what ID is passed.

if ( divId == 'b ) {
    Code to change b div
}

Comment: I just removed jquery. No jquery for this.

Comment: Okay. Then you can still use the getElementById stuff but set up your function the way I described at the bottom. That should make sure it all doesn't change at once